# XSLT - How to manage CDATA as common content?

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

I am trying to use xslt to render an xml file generated by a software in use at my work.
There are some CDATA content in the xml. When I transform it the content of the CDATA is displayed as text but I would like it is only not shown.
I found a way to make it empty so that nothing appear while I don't need to exploit it but I have to manage all cases.

My question is : 
How can I manage all the CDATA content as standard text (accessible with value-of) so that it will not appear while I don't select it for rendering ?

The xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Domain>
  <Properties>
    <Property id="DOM00000" key="mykey1" value="value1"/>
    <Property id="DOM00001" key="mykey2" value="value2"/>
  </Properties>
  <Tokens>
    <Token name="token1" comment=""><![CDATA[mydata1---blah-blah-blah]]></Token>
    <Token name="token2" comment=""><![CDATA[mydata2---blah-blah-blah]]></Token>
  </Tokens>
  <Resources>
    <Resource name="res1" type="W" current="0">
      <Value><![CDATA[10]]></Value>
    </Resource>
    <Resource name="res2" type="W" current="0">
      <Value><![CDATA[10]]></Value>
    </Resource>
  </Resources>
</Domain>
```

The xsl file I am using is this one :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/Domain/Properties">
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">id</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">key</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">value</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="/Domain/Properties/Property">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@key" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Domain/Tokens/Token">
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit** Here is what I use :

```
<form method="POST">
    <label for="xmlfileinput">Fichier XML</label><input type="file" name="myxmlfile" id="xmlfileinput" accept=".xml"><br>
    <label for="xslfileinput">Fichier XSL</label><input type="file" name="myxslfile" id="xslfileinput" accept=".xsl"><br>       
    <input type="button" onclick="handleFiles()">
</form>

function handleFiles(e) {
    var myxmlfile = document.getElementById("xmlfileinput").files;
    var myxslfile = document.getElementById("xslfileinput").files;
    var xmlreader = new FileReader();
    var xslreader = new FileReader();
    xmlreader.onload = function() {
        var xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlreader.result, "text/xml");
        xslreader.onload = function() {
            var xsl = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xslreader.result, "text/xml");
            if (window.ActiveXObject /*|| xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document"*/)
              {
              ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
              document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
              }
            // code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
            else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
              {
              xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
              xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
              resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
              while (document.getElementById("example").firstChild) {
document.getElementById("example").removeChild(document.getElementById("example").firstChild);
                }
             document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
              }
        };
        xslreader.readAsText(myxslfile[0]); 
    };
    xmlreader.readAsText(myxmlfile[0]);   
}
```

In the result with these files the "mydata..." from the Tokens are not shown but the "10" from the Ressources are here.

Thanks

Comment: What output exactly do you expect based on your given input ?

Comment: However, XSLT sees the data after CDATA tags are stripped. It will see exactly the same content as if the CDATA tags are not there. So you cannot differentiate tags having `CDATA`.

Comment: In the normal XSLT tool chain the XML parser parses the XML and the XSLT processor operates on a tree model that contains text nodes, independent on the original lexical markup. So in a normal setting the XSLT code does not even know whether there was a CDATA section or normal text in the input. Unless you plugin a tool like LexEv http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/ your XSLT code will have no way to handle CDATA sections differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is not with the elements containing CDATA sections, but with your template's match pattern.

You start by:

```
<xsl:template match="/Domain/Properties">
```

which leaves other children of the root element `Domain` - namely `Tokens` and `Resources` - to be processed by other templates.

You do have a template matching a `Token`, but not one matching a `Resource`. So `Resources` (as well as any other branches your XML might have) is handled by the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule). This results in **all** their text (not only text in CDATA sections) being copied to the output.

This has already been mentioned in previous answer. However the solution is not to chase after individual horses, but rather to close the barn door:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/Domain">
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">id</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">key</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">value</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Properties/Property">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@key" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) But I plan to use this table only for Properties, other templates will be created. I guess I will keep the select="Proterty" for table rows and embed the whole table in <xsl:for-each select="Properties"><table border="1">...</table></xsl:for-each>

Comment: *"But I plan to use this table only for Properties, other templates will be created."*  I am afraid I don't understand what that means.

Comment: This, but not sure it is the best way to do it : <xsl:template match="/Domain">
 <xsl:for-each select="Properties">
  <table border="1">
   <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
   <th style="text-align:left">id</th>
   <th style="text-align:left">key</th>
   <th style="text-align:left">value</th>
   </tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="Property">
    <tr>

Comment: If you have multiple `Properties` elements, and you want to create a separate table for each one of them, then that's what you should do. I still don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: There is a single `Properties` in the file with many `Property`. This table is made for them, but the table header is only relevant for `Properties`. I assumed that the xsl you provided would display the table head even if no `Properties` is found (which could be good too when I think about it).

Comment: If there's only a single `Properties`, you could do `<xsl:template match="/Domain"><xsl:apply-templates select="Properties"/></xsl:template>` and create the table in a template matching `Properties`. But `<xsl:for-each select="Properties">` will do the same thing - it's only a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule), especially

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

It means that all the document is traversed reaching `Value` elements.

**Solution:** add another empty template like the one you already have.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/Domain/Properties">
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">id</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">key</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">value</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="/Domain/Properties/Property">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@key" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Domain/Tokens/Token|/Domain/Resources"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I know how to get rid of them one by one, each one with its own "match". I am looking for a global solution, without having to hardcode the each path. I kept only 2 different CDATA for the example. The real file contains much more at different depth and so on.