# Xpath - How to get all existing attributes name of siblings

Tags: xslt, xpath

The goal is simple. I'm trying to build a table with attributes in columns.

My problem : Some siblings don't have the same attributes as the first one.
When I build the table head I retrieve the attributes name of the first node and then hope that attributes of the following siblings will be the same in the same order. That is not the case.
I get only columns `id, key, value, myattr1` and the `myattr2` attribute is placed in the `myattr1` column.

For building the table, I want to get columns  : `id, key, value, myattr1, myattr2`

How can I retrieve the whole list of existing attributes for the node I am working on and loop over it?

I am still working the same js and form (see link at the bottom). It now requires bootstrap (css and js).

I slightly changed the xml. Here it is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Domain>
  <Properties id="myid">
    <Property id="DOM00000" key="mykey1" value="value1" myattr2="Mail"/>
    <Property id="DOM00001" key="mykey2" value="value2" myattr1="EveryDay"/>
  </Properties>
  <Tokens>
    <Token name="token1" comment="" ><![CDATA[mydata1---blah-blah-blah]]></Token>
    <Token name="token2" comment="" ><![CDATA[mydata2---blah-blah-blah]]></Token>
  </Tokens>
  <Resources>
    <Resource name="res1" type="W" current="0">
      <Value><![CDATA[10]]></Value>
    </Resource>
    <Resource name="res2" type="W" current="0">
      <Value><![CDATA[10]]></Value>
    </Resource>
  </Resources>
</Domain>
```

The current state of the xsl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">container</xsl:attribute>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <xsl:call-template name="tabs" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="div">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">tab-content</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <xsl:call-template name="tabcontent" />
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="tabs">
    <xsl:variable name="active">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*"></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>active</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="li">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">nav-item <xsl:value-of select="$active" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">#<xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">nav-link</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="data-toggle">tab</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:element>      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tabcontent">
    <xsl:variable name="activetab">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*"></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>active in</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">container tab-pane fade <xsl:value-of select="$activetab" /></xsl:attribute>
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /></h3>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr><xsl:for-each select="./*[1]/@*"><th><xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /></th></xsl:for-each></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="./*"><tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./@*"><td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td></xsl:for-each></tr>
                </tr></xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT - How to manage CDATA as common content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54832435/xslt-how-to-manage-cdata-as-common-content)

### Edit :

Thanks to [Tim-C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7585/tim-c) answer
Here is the full xsl working for my use case :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="attrs" match="/*/*/*/@*" use="concat(name(../..), '|', name())" />   

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">container</xsl:attribute>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <xsl:call-template name="tabs" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="div">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">tab-content</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <xsl:call-template name="tabcontent" />
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="tabs">
    <xsl:variable name="active">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*"></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>active</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="li">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">nav-item <xsl:value-of select="$active" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">#<xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">nav-link</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="data-toggle">tab</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:element>      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tabcontent">
    <xsl:variable name="activetab">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*"></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>active in</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="attrs" select="*/@*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('attrs', concat(name(../..), '|', name()))[1])]" />
    <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">container tab-pane fade <xsl:value-of select="$activetab" /></xsl:attribute>
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /></h3>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$attrs">
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
                </th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <tr>
                <xsl:variable name="current" select="." />
                <xsl:for-each select="$attrs">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$current/@*[name() = name(current())]" />
                </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
  </table>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="toto"></xsl:template>




</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You stylehsheet is currently using version 1.0, but what actual XSLT processor do you use? It will be a little bit simpler if you can use XSLT 2.0? (You could use `xsl:for-each-group` or maybe `distinct-values` to get the list of distinct attribute names in XSLT 2.0). Thanks!

Comment: I let you give a look to my previous question (the link). I am using some javascript to get the files and apply the transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you make use of here is a technique called Muenchian Grouping to get a list of distinct attributes, based on their name.

However, although the question just mentions about `id, key, value, myattr1, myattr2`, which are the `Property` attributes, it looks like you want to repeat it for the `Token` and `Resource` nodes too (i.e. you are trying to be generic). In this case, you define a key like so, which takes into account the main element name

```
<xsl:key name="attrs" match="/*/*/*/@*" use="concat(name(../..), '|', name())" />
```

Then, for a given element (such as `Properties`) you can get distinct attributes like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="attrs" select="*/@*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('attrs', concat(name(../..), '|', name()))[1])]" />
```

This can then be used to get the headers, and access the relevant attributes for each row.

Try this (abridged) XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:key name="attrs" match="/*/*/*/@*" use="concat(name(../..), '|', name())" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:call-template name="tabcontent" />
  </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tabcontent">
  <xsl:variable name="attrs" select="*/@*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('attrs', concat(name(../..), '|', name()))[1])]" />
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$attrs">
          <th>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
          </th>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <tr>
          <xsl:variable name="current" select="." />
          <xsl:for-each select="$attrs">
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="$current/@*[name() = name(current())]" />
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYi7

Comment: Thank you :) Now I will see how it behaves with a relative key as my real xml is going deeper than the example.